# bloom filter algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bloom-filter, spelling

I need the bloom filter algorithm in JavaScript for a spell checker> I have a big huge list of words. Does any have the algorithm

Answer (score 4):

Try to search on google before asking here.. The first page which is showing up is http://www.jasondavies.com/bloomfilter/ so try it..

Comment: This is very well explained and the code seems clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from this web:
http://la.ma.la/misc/js/bloomfilter/
concretely:
http://la.ma.la/misc/js/bloomfilter/bloomfilter.js

Comment: Links are dead in this answer.